# Show that $I_{(0,\theta)}(x_1) \dots I_{(0,\theta)}(x_n) = I_{(0,\theta)}(x_{(n)})$

Tags: statistics

Show that $I_{(0,\theta)}(x_1) \dots I_{(0,\theta)}(x_n) = I_{(0,\theta)}(x_{(n)})$

where $x_{(n)}$ is the order statistic, and $X = (X_1,..., X_n)\sim U(0,\theta)$ iid.

I can show that it is equal to $I_{(0,\infty)}(x_{(1)}) I_{(-\infty,\theta)}(x_{(n)})$, but not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: $I_{(0,\infty)}(x_1)I_{(-\infty,\theta)}(x_{(n)})$ is the same as $I_{(0,\theta)}(x_{(n)})$ in this case.

Comment: I don't understand how to show that

Comment: Nothing to show really. Product of the two indicators is the indicator of the intersection of $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,\theta)$.

Comment: But then which variable should be inside the indicator function? couldn't it equally be $x_{(1)}$?

Comment: The full string of inequality is $0<x_1,\ldots,x_n<\theta\implies 0<x_{(1)},x_{(n)}<\theta$, where $x_{(1)}$ can be dropped from the condition as it is redundant in this context.

Comment: I understand it if it was just $x_1,...,x_n<\theta \iff x_{(n)}<\theta$, but doesn't the lower limit imply that $x_{(1)}$ is not redundant?

Comment: Along with $x_{(1)}>0$ and $x_{(1)}<x_{(n)}$, you have just $0<x_{(n)}<\theta$. You can keep the $x_{(1)}$ in the indicator also, makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If $0\le x_i\le \theta$ for all $i$, and $ x_i \le x_{(n)}$, then $\cap_{i=1}^{n}\{0\le x_{i}\le \theta\} = \cap_{i=1}^{n}\{0\le x_{i}\le x_{(n)}\le \theta\}= \{0\le x_{(n)}\le \theta\}$

Comment: Can't the same argument be made for $x_{(1)}$?

Comment: Sure, as $0 \le x_{(1)} \le x_i \le x_{(n)} \le \theta$ for all $i$

Answer (score 0):

You are completely right that $$I_{(0,\theta)}(x_1) \dots I_{(0,\theta)}(x_n) = I_{(0,\infty)}(x_{(1)})I_{(0,\theta)}(x_{(n)}).$$ Check initial equality $$I_{(0,\theta)}(x_1) \dots I_{(0,\theta)}(x_n) = I_{(0,\theta)}(x_{(n)})$$ at $x_{(1)}=-1$, $x_{(n)}<\theta$.  L.h.s. equals to $0$ and r.h.s. equals to $1$.

Note that this cases have zero probability: $\mathbb P(x_{(1)}\leq 0)=0$. So the initial equality can be considered as equality with probability $1$: 
$$I_{(0,\theta)}(x_1) \dots I_{(0,\theta)}(x_n) = I_{(0,\theta)}(x_{(n)}) \text{ a.s.}$$
In statistics, it is usual to skip letters *a.s.* since we cannot expect to see some $X_i\leq 0$ in a sample from Uniform $(0,\theta)$ distribution.

Comment: Isn't it also true that $P(X_{(n)}>\theta) = 0$ ?

Comment: Sure. But note that this r.h.s. is also a function of $\theta$ and can be used to estimate $\theta$ given $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ as MLE. In this problem we must consider all possible values of $\theta$: $\theta\leq x_{(n)}$ as well as $\theta>x_{(n)}$. So, if you look at this product as the function of elementary event $\omega$ given $\theta$, it differs from last indicator or from $1$ only on event of zero probability. If you look at it as a function of $\theta$ given samples which are already positive, then $\omega$ is fixed. Then it is $I_{(0,\theta)}(x_{(n)}) = I_{(x_{(n)},\infty)}(\theta)$.